# store pandas dataframe into sqlite3 database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sql
sea_level_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\SeaLevel.csv", skiprows=3)
database = "database.db"
conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
sea_level_df.to_sql(name='Sea_Level', con=conn)
con = sql.connect('Sea_Level')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT* FROM "Sea_Level";''')
cur.fetchall()
con.close()
```

I'm basically trying to store a dataframe into a database for sqlite3. I'm using jupyter notebook. when I run the script above, I get this:

```
ValueError: Table 'Sea_Level' already exists.
```

Comment: It's not clear what your desired result is, but you can use the `if_exists=` parameter to overwrite or append to the table. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

As [@AlexK mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106169/store-pandas-dataframe-into-sqlite3-database#comment130842305_74106169) in the comments: Use `if_exists='append'` or `if_exists='replace'` as needed.

```py
sea_level_df.to_sql(name='Sea_Level', con=conn, if_exists='append')
```

Btw, the error you're getting is [documented as expected behaviour](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

> if_exists {‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’
>
> How to behave if the table already exists.
>
> - fail: Raise a ValueError.
> - replace: Drop the table before inserting new values.
> - append: Insert new values to the existing table.